# RNN Pod has not been added to Podfile

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to add react native navigation to a out of the box, hello world react native app. I am following the steps in this doc.

https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing

after running the script, I run into this output.

```
Running Android postlink script.

Linking MainApplication...
   Extending NavigationApplication
   Changing host implementation to NavigationReactNativeHost
   Removing call to SOLoader.init()
MainApplication.java linked successfully!

Linking MainActivity...
   Extending NavigationActivity
   Removing getMainComponentName function
MainActivity linked successfully!

Linking root build.gradle...
   Adding RNNKotlinVersion to extension block
   Adding Kotlin plugin
   Updating minSdkVersion to 19
Root build.gradle linked successfully!

Running iOS postlink script.

Linking AppDelegate...
   Removing Unneeded imports
   All imports have been removed
   Importing ReactNativeNavigation.h
   Bootstrapping Navigation
   Removing Application launch content
   Application Launch content has been removed
AppDelegate linked successfully!

Updating Podfile...
   RNN Pod has not been added to Podfile

React Native Navigation link is completed. Check the logs above for more information.

   If any of the steps failed, check the installation docs and go through the necessary steps manually:
   https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing#manual-installation

When you're done, don't forget to update the index.js file as mentioned in docs!

Thank you for using React Native Navigation!
```

I try to add the pod manually, I get this.

```
[!] There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `ReactNativeNavigation` in `Podfile`:

- ReactNativeNavigation (from `../node_modules/react-native-navigation`)
- ReactNativeNavigation (from `../node_modules/react-native-navigation/ReactNativeNavigation.podspec`)
```

I am just trying to add react navigation to react native app. that is it. How do I get past this issue?

I have already raised the issue here https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/6470 but posting the issue here as well, if someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a minor discussion about this on the above linked GitHub issue, with solved solution.

Posting a brief solution here for the benefit of others.

Step 1 - add the following to your pod file.

```
target 'baribasicreact' do
  pod 'ReactNativeNavigation' , :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-navigation'
```

Step 2 - install pods.

```
cd iOS & pod install
```

more details in the linked GitHub issue in the question.